# Spring Batch service processing same doc infinitely

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-batch

I have spring batch job which reads from one mongo collection and writes to another, the reader reads using mongoTemplate’s findOne query to find document with particular value for name field. Source collection has only two documents with different name field values and I am using chunk size as 1, so ideally job should finish after reading one time, but it’s reading the same doc infinitely. What should be the cause of this behaviour and how can I define my reader to avoid processing the same doc repeatedly? Below is custom reader snippet

```
    @Override
    public Employee read(){
        Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("name").is("Sama");
        return mongoTemplate.findOne(query, Employee.class);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reader must return `null` at some point to signal to the framework that the datasource is exhausted. This is mentioned in the contract of the [ItemReader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemReader.html#read()) interface.

The code you shared always returns the same document and never `null`. Therefore Spring Batch does not know when to finish the step and continues to read the same document infinitely.